# Substitution cipher that takes position into account

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm working on a project where I'm to show some information to the user based on a ciphered text.

I already know the cipher, meaning, I know how to crack it. I know of the simple substitution cipher, but that one will not work in this case.

I have a code consisting solely of numbers 0-9 with repetition of 0-10. So basically a code with 0-10 characters consisting only of numbers. This code is then run through a cipher and translated into a mix of capital letters, non-capital letters and numbers.

Simple enough, and I would probably be able to write a dechiperer to translate that back to numbers. But this also takes the position of the numbers in the code into account.

Meaning: a code: 1234 could translate into Ar5Q but the code: 4321 could translate into B6up and not: Q5rA as you would expect from a simple substitution cipher.

Could anyone point me in the direction of how to create such a cipher?

And a bonus question. Is it possible to generate a dechiperer from a table or a dictionary?

EDIT:

I have this table:

[image]

The code: 1234 would become: H8o6

H8o6 is the string I recieve and decode.

I solved this by creating a dictionary

```
Dictionary<KeyValuePair<string, int>, int> translator = new Dictionary<KeyValuePair<string, int>, int>();
```

And I added all entries to the dictionary like this:

```
translator.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("N", 0), 0);
        translator.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("H", 0), 1);
        translator.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("r", 0), 2);
        translator.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("x", 0), 3);
        translator.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Y", 0), 4);
        translator.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("e", 0), 5);
        translator.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("z", 0), 6);
        translator.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("t", 0), 7);
        translator.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("L", 0), 8);
        translator.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("l", 0), 9);
        translator.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("t", 1), 0);
        translator.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("I", 1), 1);
        translator.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("8", 1), 2);
        translator.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("r", 1), 3);
        translator.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("X", 1), 4);
        translator.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("K", 1), 5);
```

This just feels super ineffective. But I can't get my head around how else to do it.

Marked Matts answer. But what I was actually looking for I got though comments :-)

Comment: Ok - so add a number for the position in the string. Not sure what your question is. For background, you might check out this because it seems like you are almost moving in this direction: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad

Comment: @MattBurland I wish I could tell you exactly, I temporarily solved the problem by creating a dictionary, consisting of a KeyValuePair, which then consists of a string with the ciphered character and an integer representing the position in the code, and an integer that then represents with number the KeyValuePair would correspond to.

So the question would be, is there a simpler way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more. It's really hard to follow what you are saying. So you had a `Dictionary<KeyValuePair<string,int>,int>`? Is what you want, basically, to have each character be enciphered with a completely different cipher? So something not dissimilar to the one-time pad?

Comment: So, yes then. Use a 2D array. Or at the very least, I'd rearrange that dictionary to make it easier to encode by having it be keyed off the `original, position` and returning `encoded letter`. So `Dictionary<KeyValuePair<int,int>,string>` and if your table isn't too big, I'd just create a separate dictionary for deciphering as trying to reverse it will be a pain otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I'm understanding this correctly, you have something like this:

```
char[] cipher = ['A','r','5','Q','T','g','6','7','u']
```

And you are encoding a list of numbers like this:

```
int[] msg = [1,2,3,4];
```

by doing something like this:

```
encoded[i] = cipher[msg[i]-1];
```

In other words, you are using the number in the msg as an index to your cipher.

So if you want to add position to it, just add in position and mod it (to keep it in range). Something like:

```
encoded[i] = cipher[(msg[i] - 1 + i) % cipher.length];
```

So now you encoded message would be (if I haven't messed this up - I'm doing it in my head):

```
A 5 T 6
```

Now, if your idea is to have completely separate ciphers for each position in the string, then I think your best bet is to have a 2D array. Something like (shortened to 2 characters for sanity):

```
char[,] cipher = {
    { 'A', 'N' },
    { 'C', '2' },
    { 'a', 'E' }
}
```

Then you'd index it like this:

```
encoded[i] = cipher[i,msg[i]-1];
```

Of course, now you need to make sure the dimensions of your array are *length of message x range of message characters*